# Where can I farm Aqua Pearls?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I recently pulled [Shylt](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Shylt) who is a Barrier Mage, and to awaken him I need to find [Aqua Pearls](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Aqua_Pearl).

The wiki says that they are available from

> Chamber of Awakening (BGN, INT, ADV)

However, I have used my entire NRG bar on the ADV dungeon and got no drops. Is there a more reliable way to farm this item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following that same link you provided, it also suggests enemies that drop the item in the campaign.

Doing some more research, some suggestions have stated the "best" place to farm is the [Ballen Passage Entrance](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Ballen_Passage_Entrance) stage (found in Dirnado).

The levels that contain monsters that drop these items are:

- Downhill
- Narrow Path
- Crossroads

These missions also only require 4 energy each, as opposed to the 5 - 15 that the Chamber of Awakening trials require.

Comment: Thanks I got a pearl on my first try of the Downhill stage.